# dateTimepicker and monthlycalender question?

Tags: c#

I want to use a dateTimePicker and monthlycalender on the form..this how I want it to work. if I change the dateTimepicker value the date is highlighted on the monthlycalender  how do i do that, any help please?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the selection of the monthly calender using [SetSelectionRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.setselectionrange.aspx). Pass [DateTimePicker.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value.aspx) for both parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Place the information that Daniel gave you in the

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
```

event handler.